# makefile: escape character / expand variable differs with users

Tags: variables, unix, makefile, escaping

I have a makefile where a rule has below echo in a recipe :

```
@echo "DUPW \$(VAR1).FILE*"
```

The value of variable VAR1 = DATA.SUBVOL

When running the make (on OSS, a Unix like OS) under user A it echoes it the way I want it :

```
DUPW $DATA.SUBVOL.FILE*
```

But when running the same make under user B it echoes :

```
DUPW \DATA.SUBVOL.FILE*
```

What causes above different behaviour between the 2 users ?

The diffent behaviour also occurs when I change the recipe as follows :

```
@echo "DUPW \$$$(VAR1).DICT*"
```

But now user A echoes it incorrect :

```
DUPW $.SUBVOL.FILE*
```

and user B echoes it in the way I want it :

```
DUPW $DATA.SUBVOL.FILE*
```

Comment: Possible differences include: (i) the users are using different makefiles; (ii) the users are accessing different `make` commands; (iii) the users are causing different recipes to run; possibly because of (iv) different environment variable values or different files in the working directory.  These are not the only possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not familiar with *OSS, a Unix like OS* so I don't know what make implementation is on it.  If you run `make --version` does it tell you anything useful?  There's certainly no `make` implementation I'm familiar with that will emit both those behaviors.  Are you **sure** that both users are running the *exact same* `make` implementation?

Basically, the behavior of `make` for User B is correct according to the POSIX standard.  A recipe line like this:

```
@echo "DUPW \$(VAR1).FILE*"
```

will first expand the makefile variable `$(VAR1)` (in POSIX make, backslashes are not special in any way; they're just a character like any other character) and so if `VAR1` has the value `DATA.SUBVOL` the result of expansion will be:

```
@echo "DUPW \DATA.SUBVOL.FILE*"
```

If you want to put a literal `$` in the output, you escape it from `make` by writing `$$`.  Then, since this is in a double-quoted value you have to escape the literal `$` from the shell as well, which uses `\` and so you'd use:

```
@echo "DUPW \$$$(VAR1).FILE*"
```

It might be simpler to understand if you switch to single quotes instead in your shell command, so the shell won't expand.  Then you can forgo the backslash:

```
@echo 'DUPW $$$(VAR1).FILE*'
```

I have no idea what implementation of `make` is being used, but the behavior seen by User A is wrong / is not conforming to the POSIX standard for `make`.

Comment: I really strongly urge you to _remove_ all the `@` chars from your recipes until after your makefile is 100% working.  Hiding this output makes it very hard to debug your makefile.